# gstreamer filesrc is not working with error "sink-actual-sink-d3dvideo", but gst-launch is working correctly on windows

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I want to read a file and playback. very simple.

*windows10, visual studio 2017 community.

in command prompt, this is working correctly.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="C:/test.webm" ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

but my code is not working, this.

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  ..... declare variable

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Create the elements */
  source = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "source");
  decode = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "decode");
  sink = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "sink");
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, decode, sink, NULL);
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT(source), "location", "C:/test.webm", NULL);
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);

  ... error processing
}
```

and my error is this

```
Error received from element sink-actual-sink-d3dvideo: Output window was closed
Debugging information: ../sys/d3dvideosink/d3dhelpers.c(1911): d3d_render_buffer (): /GstPipeline:test-pipeline/GstAutoVideoSink:sink/GstD3DVideoSink:sink-actual-sink-d3dvideo
```

please help me what is my problem.

- my code is almost same to [official tutorial](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/concepts.html). I just changed videotestsrc to filesrc, add the decodebin between source and sink, set the property for giving media file location

Comment: The `decodebin` element is a bit more tricky. It does not expose any pads by default you could connect. Instead when the pipeline is running it starts exposing pads depending on the media being played. You need to check for `pad-added` signal and connect the exposed pad to your downstream element.

Comment: The Basic tutorial 3 (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/dynamic-pipelines.html) has a pipeline very similar to yours, and explains how to handle pad-added signal

Comment: @FlorianZwoch thanks. I have one more question. Is that log saying about missing decode's sink pad problem?? Actually, I want to understand debug log for making another pipeline.

Comment: @Tom thanks for your link! could you please read my above comment?